# how to querying datetime with android on Kinvey

Tags: kinvey

I want to query using date.

on API Console , It really works well.

> /appdata/[keydata]/Updates/?query={"_kmd.lmt":{"$gte": "2013-03-07T09:09:24+0000"}}

but I don't know how to on android.

```
    RefreshDate = "2013-02-20T10:04:05.511Z";

    Log.d(TAG,"RefreshDate="+RefreshDate);

    MappedAppdata updates = mKinveyClient.mappeddata(UpdateEntity.class, "Updates");
    SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery();
    query.orderByAscending("_kmd.lmt");
    query.addCriteria("_kmd.lmt", ">=", RefreshDate);
```

error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unterminated object at character 19 of {$gte: 2013-02-20 10:04:05}

I want to know how to querying on android.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of RefreshDate?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  I work at Kinvey.

I would recommend upgrading to [version 2.0](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/downloads) of the Android Library.  It uses a different (and better) data model and has more robust querying capabilities.